# How can I add a OneToMany field in Symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, entity, one-to-many

I try to configure a OneToMany field to my Symfony app:

my Entity: `Project.php`

```
 /**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", mappedBy="project")
*/
private $event;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->enabled = false;
    $this->event = new ArrayCollection();
}


public function getEvent()
{
    return $this->event;
}

public function setEvent($event): self
{
    $this->event = $event;

    return $this;
}

public function addEvent(Event $event): self
{
    $this->event[] = $event;

    return $this;
}

public function removeEvent(Event $event)
{
    if ($this->event->contains($event)) {
        $this->event->removeElement($event);
        $event->removeEvent($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

my Entity `event.php`

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Project", inversedBy="event")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
 private $project;
```

my Controller `ProjectController.php`

```
  protected function mapDataToEntity(array $data, Project $entity): void{
    if ($event = $data['event'] ?? null) {
            foreach ($event as $e) {
                $entity->setEvent($e);
            }
            
     }
  }
```

But I get the error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`mysite`.`#sql-172bb_1b3`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ED7D872A166D1F9I` FOREIGN
> KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `app_project` (`id`))

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your "Project" table empty? Looks like an existing record is triggering the violation since it does not have the constraint set

Comment: the name of the table in the database is `app_project`. Is this probably the problem?

Comment: I'd clear the table if possible the ensure the content isn't the problem. Also you should use "addEvent" in ProjectController since you're only adding one event, and your "setEvent" method reallocate the field instead of populating the array

Comment: @Maniax I cleared the table but the error is still there when I want to make a database update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#setting-information-from-the-inverse-side),:

> To update a relationship in the database, **you must set the
> relationship on the owning side**. The owning side is always where the
> ManyToOne mapping is set.

So when persisting the `Event` the related `Project` is not set, and the constraint fails. You should be calling `$event->setProject();`.

[MakerBundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/current/index.html#installation) would usually autogenerate the code to do it from the inverse side (`Project`, in this instance), but that bit is missing from your code. You can regenerate the entities using the bundle (`bin/console make:entity Project --regenerate` should do it) or add the bit that's missing, since I don't think you are using the bundle:

```
// Project.php
public function addEvent(Event $event): self
{
    if (!$this->event->contains($event)) {
        $this->event[] = $event;
        $event->setProject($this);  // This is the crucial line
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As a side note, I'd rename the property to `events`, since it clearly denotes a collection, but that's irrelevant for this issue. Those kinds of little details would be taken care of by using MakerBundle.

Also, as noted by [@Maniax](https://stackoverflow.com/u/6045908) in the comments, the controller should read

```
foreach ($event as $e) {
    $entity->addEvent($e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated everything as you suggested, but I still get the error when I want to update the database

Comment: Your update creates another error:`App\Entity\Project::addEvent(): Argument #1 ($event) must be of type App\Entity\Event, int given, called in /Users/mySite/src/Controller/Admin/ProjectController.php on line 111`

Comment: @peace_love That seems to be unrelated to the entity itself, but what you receive in the controller. What's the `$data['event']` array? I was assuming it was an array of `Events` but judging by the error it must be an array of `event_id`s. If that's the case, you can load them using the repository or dive into [data transformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html). I'd suggest you ask another question focusing on the form / controller, as in this one might get a bit unwildly.

Comment: I had to clear the database "events" and then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Did you change something in entity after migration ? Try to delete table, run php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force and check with php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate. Also you can delete set method, this will be collection.

Comment: Thank you! The error message actually occures when I want to update the database

Comment: I had to clear the database "events" and then it worked !